# Postgresql get adjacent record as a column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I wanted to get the adjacent record as a column on the select query of the Postgresql

here is my schema.

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  id            serial primary key,
  title         text,
  content       text
);
```

and here are the sample records.

```
insert into post (title, content) values
('War and Peace snippet', 'Although Tolstoy wrote most of the book, including all the narration, in Russian, significant portions of dialogue (including its opening paragraph) are written in French with characters often switching between the two languages.'),
('War and Peace snippet', ' This reflected 19th century Russian aristocracy, where French, a foreign tongue, was widely spoken and considered a language of prestige and more refined than Russian.'),
('Anna Karenina was Tolstoy''s "first true novel"', 'Widely regarded as a pinnacle in realist fiction, Tolstoy considered Anna Karenina his first true novel, when he came to consider War and Peace to be more than a novel.'),
('War and Peace snippet', 'It has been suggested[14] that it is a deliberate literary device employed by Tolstoy, to use French to portray artifice and insincerity as the language of the theater and deceit while Russian emerges as a language of sincerity, honesty and seriousness.');
```

you can use this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e6dd6.

I wanted a next and previous record id as a column when i select a id.

```
select po.id, n.id as next_id, p.id as previous_id
from post po, post n, post p
where po.id=3 and n.id> po.id and p.id < po.id limit 1;
```

but it does not gives me correct result. the `next_id` should be `4` and `previous_id` should be `2` in ideal case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select p.*,
       lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id,
       lead(id) over (order by id) as next_id
from post p;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9848cc6e394b3fce7f10af5b97feb3ea) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  If you want to filter for a particular id, you need to use a subquery:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id,
             lead(id) over (order by id) as next_id
      from post p
     ) p
where id = 3;
```